# Problem with "Sign in with Apple"-Apple logo is not displaying when I use "Sign in with Apple" button on my web app

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Problem with "Sign in with Apple" button log:  I'm trying to integrate "Sign in with Apple" button in my web app, I followed the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple)  but when I run it the button comes with weird characters as "ï£¿â€…Sign in with Apple". The svg file is not loading properly for the logo and I also used meta tag to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this very same issue, and it truns out it was a CSS related issue, specifically font related issue, make sure your font related rules, dont messing up with apple rules,

In my case i had this following css rules

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Barlow";
    src: font-url("BarlowCondensed-SemiBold.ttf");
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Barlow";
    src: font-url("BarlowCondensed-Regular.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Barlow";
    src: font-url("BarlowCondensed-Bold.ttf");
    font-weight: bold;
}

html * {
    font-family: "Barlow";
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

when I just commented out this part, it started to showing up again

```
html * {
        font-family: "Barlow";
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```